# Perform column rename and slicing on multiple pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Example

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'col1': [1,"newcolumn1name",5, 8,15 ], 'col2':[5,"newcolumn2name"10,15, 20]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df1=df
df2=df

df
Out[24]: 
             col1            col2
0               1               5
1  newcolumn1name  newcolumn2name
2               5              10
3               8              15
4              15              20
```

What I would like to do with this example is to drop the first row and rename the columns with the string of the second row.

I can do this with the following code (complete python newcomer here):

```
df=df[1:]
new_header = df.iloc[0]
df=df[1:]
df.columns = new_header

df
Out[26]: 
1 newcolumn1name newcolumn2name
2              5             10
3              8             15
4             15             20
```

Now I'd like to be able to this over both df1 and df2, as defined in the example. I've tried lists, dictionaries, and map, but I ran into issues with all of them.

Can anyone think of the simplest way to do it? On my real data, I'll have six to ten data frames (~1000x8000) to run it on.

Comment: Are you reading this from a CSV somewhere? If so, you can probably just skip that first line on read and avoid all this manipulation.

Comment: It's from a transposed csv, so at some point I'll figure out how to exclude on import, and then I'll be able to skip that first line. Thanks for the tip though!

Comment: [`read_csv()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) has a `skiprows` argument that I think will make your life easier.

Comment: I think that you're right, but have to transpose after import (or at least I think that I do), so that's where I'm currently stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC

```
l=[df1,df2]

[ d[1:].T.set_index(1).T for d in l]


Out[221]: 
[1 newcolumn1name newcolumn2name
 2              5             10
 3              8             15
 4             15             20, 1 newcolumn1name newcolumn2name
 2              5             10
 3              8             15
 4             15             20]
```

Update

```
l=[df1,df2]
df1,df2=[ d[1:].T.set_index(1).T for d in l]
df1
Out[226]: 
1 newcolumn1name newcolumn2name
2              5             10
3              8             15
4             15             20
df2
Out[227]: 
1 newcolumn1name newcolumn2name
2              5             10
3              8             15
4             15             20
```

Update 2

```
variables = locals()
for x,d in enumerate(l):
    variables["df{0}".format(x+1)]=d[1:].T.set_index(1).T
df1
Out[231]: 
1 newcolumn1name newcolumn2name
2              5             10
3              8             15
4             15             20
df2
Out[232]: 
1 newcolumn1name newcolumn2name
2              5             10
3              8             15
4             15             20
```

Comment: Not quite. I'd like to return two data frames, df1 and df2, that have the above slicing and renaming performed.

Comment: Perfect. Is there a way to pull the names from the list or am I stuck hardcoding the "df1", "df2". Like I said in the beginning, I don't have a ton of dFs to work with, so hardcoding isn't too bad.

Answer (score 1):

You can turn you logic into a function and use [`df.pipe`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pipe.html). Something like the below could work (untested).

```
def formatter(df):
    df = df[1:]
    new_header = df.iloc[0]
    df = df[1:]
    df.columns = new_header
    return df

for my_df in [df1, df2, df3, df4, df5, df6]:
    my_df  = my_df.pipe(formatter)
```

Comment: Hi JP, thanks for throwing something up there. This indeed returns the correct formatting but only on one such dataframe. I had tried something similar to this but unfortunately got the same result as this.

Comment: @Sparky_47. OK, I'm afraid I can't help further unless you have specific data & error message to share.

Comment: Hey JP, the out of this is a single dataframe that is **my_d*8f. There is no error message, as it runs cleanly, but only appears to output a single dataframe when I would like to run over both df1 and df2.

Answer (score 1):

Yet another solution for Pandas 0.21+:

```
In [21]: lst = [df1, df2]

In [22]: def renamer(df):
             return (df.iloc[2:]
                       .set_axis(df.iloc[1], axis='columns', inplace=False)
                       .rename_axis(None,1))

In [23]: new = list(map(renamer, lst))

In [24]: new[0]
Out[24]:
  newcolumn1name newcolumn2name
2              5             10
3              8             15
4             15             20

In [25]: new[1]
Out[25]:
  newcolumn1name newcolumn2name
2              5             10
3              8             15
4             15             20
```

Comment: Although your example looks great, I get <br /> <br />Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-39-3c58faebd934>", line 1, in <module>
    new = list(map(renamer, lst))

  File "<ipython-input-38-cbdf747c08db>", line 3, in renamer
    .set_axis(df.iloc[1], axis='columns', inplace=False)

TypeError: set_axis() got multiple values for argument 'axis'

Comment: @Sparky_47, most probably you have an older version of Pandas. Try `axis=1` instead of `axis='columns'`